# How to prevent ASP.NET / IIS from sending my http headers when it fails

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have this case that occurs in my production environment but that I'm unable to reproduce in my dev environment. My WebApi creates an response object with status code 200 and sets some headers.

We found out that if an administrator restarts IIS, IIS sends back 500 errors **but keeps my headers**. This is a problems because I'm setting cache headers and in this case, the clients end up caching 500 responses which is really not what I want.

I suppose that this happens to requests that are still in progress when IIS decides to kill them in order to be able to restart but I was not able to prove that.

Is there a way for me to make sure I never send out 500 responses that have caching headers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for you, but want to comment on:

> I suppose that this happens to requests that are still in progress when IIS decides to kill them in order to be able to restart but I was not able to prove that.

Using a simple page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" debug="true"%>

<script runat="server">                
     void Page_Load() {        
        Response.Headers.Add("Stack","Overflow");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);     
     }
</script>
```

which takes 10 seconds to execute and adds a custom header.

Some response headers for a normal 200:

```
Content-Type:text/html
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Stack:Overflow
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

if you now set the application pool to not wait that long before shutting down the pool:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add[@name='DefaultAppPool']/processModel" -name "shutdownTimeLimit" -value "00:00:03"
```

I'm telling IIS  to shutdown the DefaultAppPool after 3 seconds regardless of running requests.

Now in the browser hit our page again and while it is executing. stop the pool or do an `iisreset.exe`

You now get a 503 (not a 500) with response headers like this:

```
Connection:close
Content-Length:326
Content-Type:text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date:Mon, 06 Jul 2015 04:21:31 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Notice that the server is no longer IIS, it is now `Microsoft-HTTPAPI` which means the request has been answered by http.sys the kernel mode part of IIS rather than the user mode part.

Also our custom http header is gone.

All this means is that your assumption above is incorrect and the 500 response must come from somewhere else.

Do you see those 500s in the IIS logs? If so they happen before the application pool is gone.

If you can't reproduce the problem locally and can't run Failed Request tracing on the production box, it may be difficult to find out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is really helpful. We had performed the same tests in dev and got the 503s too but we could not get the 500s. I did not realize that the 503 came from `Microsoft-HTTPAPI`. In prod, the 500s are in the IIS logs. We are going to enable Failed Request tracing to see that happened. I'll keep you posted.